# unable to access css js image files because .htaccess file pursing the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have use the below htaccess script to purse url for my website:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?con=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(administrator|admin)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?cms=$1&controller=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^(administrator|admin)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?cms=$1&controller=$2&action=$3 [L]
```

I have url like:

```
http://example.com/search/country-name/
```

here:

```
controller = search;
action = country-name;
```

if the url is: `http://example.com/admin/search/country-name/`

then

```
cms = admin
controller = search;
action = country-name;
```

Now problem is I am unable to access my assets file ( css, js, image, etc files ). Becacue htaccess purse those below url also!

```
-> http://example.com/assets/css/style.css
or,
-> http://example.com/assets/js/style.css
or,
-> http://example.com/assets/image/image_name.jpg
```

What should i do so that htaccess do not purse the url http://example.com/assets/ and what ever in the assets folder ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this after `RewriteEngine on` :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Like that, you avoid to rewrite real file or directory.

Comment: Seems working, i need to test more to accept it... thank you for the solution.

Comment: Ok, and don't forget to use absolute links in your html code or to add `<base href="/">` in your <head>.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(css|js|fonts|images)

into your htaccess. (css/js/fonts/images) are the folder name